# Google Bigquery API tables.insert from CSV giving invalid Source URI for local file

Tags: google-api, google-bigquery

I have a CSV file which I want to upload using the tables.insert Google Bigquery API call, this allows me to use an externalDataConfiguration where i can upload CSV files which automatically create tables in Bigquery, however I keep getting Invalid Source URI returned - the file I am uploading is sitting on my web server and is publicly accessible - I originally thought it was permissions as I was testing this on Postman, however, moving it to my webserver i get the exact same response.

An example of the curl being used is:

```
{
  "externalDataConfiguration": {
    "sourceUris": [
      "https://xxxx/datasets/testing/claims.csv"
    ],
    "sourceFormat": "CSV",
    "csvoptions": {
        "fieldDelimiter": ",",
        "skipLeadingRows": "1"
    },
    "autodetect": true
  },
  "tableReference": {
    "tableId": "TEST_THIS_UPLOAD3"
  }
}
```

I have tested this out with a google sheets dataset and that works fine however, CSV is giving me issues - response looks like:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid source URI: https://xxx/datasets/testing/laims.csv",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Invalid source URI: https://xxx/datasets/testing/claims.csv",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "invalid"
      }
    ],
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BigQuery doesn't support URLs over HTTP as you are trying to use.

BigQuery supports in this external import 3 sources:

- Cloud Storage URIs
- Google Cloud Bigtable URIs
- Google Cloud Datastore backups

these are URIs not URLs, and they point it to the file in Google cloud location, in other words: The fully-qualified URIs that point to your data in Google Cloud.

You need to put your CSV into Google Cloud and use the URI of the GCS file location in your API request.

Comment: Thanks very much, was busy looking at that, will add another step into the API to upload the csv to cloud storage first, the docs are very frustrating tbh